# pd.to_datetime output is 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0000

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string-to-datetime

```
dt_corr = dt[["date","mean_press", "maxwind", "sun_dur","mean_rel_hum", "mean_temp", "mean_cloud", "max_temp_2m", ]].dropna()
dt_corr["year"] = dt_corr.date.dt.year
dt_corr.set_index("date")
dt_corr.index = pd.to_datetime(dt_corr.index, format='%Y/%m-%d')    #####why appears format green here ????? i don't get it
dt_corr
```

The index in any output is always like this:
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000033417 ##last for digits differ
I cannot coerce my index to datetime, to finally reasample my data and plot it.
The format parameter doesn't change anything and appears in green in my codeline.
What can I do?

Comment: What is the value of `dt_corr.index` before you try to format it?

Comment: its's like 2019-12-29

Comment: Well that doesn't match the `%Y/%m-%d` pattern does it?

Comment: What is the right pattern though? So far I tried plenty of. But doesn't change it.

Comment: If you have a year (`%Y`), month (`%m`)  and day (`%d`) each separated by dashes (`-`) the pattern is `%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: I actually tried this, but the problem remains.