# Pandas date column: problem with date conversion

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column `date` in a Covid data set. The dates appear in this format `20211030` (year - month - day).

However, when converting that column, everything appears with 1970.

This is my code:

```
df["FECHA"] = pd.to_datetime(df["FECHA"], unit='s')
```

The result is this:

```
0   MI PERU 1970-08-22 21:58:27
1   SAN JUAN DE LURIGANCHO  1970-08-22 19:27:09
2   YANAHUARA   1970-08-22 19:22:01
3   CUSCO   1970-08-22 22:08:41
4   PANGOA  1970-08-22 21:58:36
```

Thank you in advance for your help, big hug.

I get this error:

ValueError: The 'datetime64' dtype has no unit. Please pass in 'datetime64[ns]' instead.

my complete code

```
import pandas as pd  
 import numpy as np  
 import matplotlib.pyplot as
 plt  from datetime import datetime 
 dataset_covid = "datasetcovid.csv"  
 df = pd.read_csv(dataset_covid, sep=";", usecols=["DISTRITO", "FECHA_RESULTADO"]) 
 df['FECHA_RESULTADO'] = df['FECHA_RESULTADO'].astype('datetime64')
```

also try this other code

```
df['FECHA_RESULTADO'] = df['FECHA_RESULTADO''].astype(str).astype('datetime64')
```

**ParserError: year 20210307 is out of range: 20210307.0**

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61579944/pd-to-datetime-output-is-1970-01-01-000000-0000

Comment: Why are you using `unit='s'`?

Comment: 20211030 is being read as if it was a unix epoch timestamp which is seconds past 1970-01-01. You need to pass a `format` argument instead of `unit`.

Comment: Look at `print(pd.to_datetime("20211030"))` and `print(pd.to_datetime(20211030))`. So try `df["FECHA"] = pd.to_datetime(df["FECHA"].astype(str))`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you don't need `pd.to_datetime` **IF** column contains strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'FECHA': ['20211030']})
print(df)

# Output:
      FECHA
0  20211030
```

Use `astype`:

```
df['FECHA'] = df['FECHA'].astype('datetime64')
print(df)

# Output:
       FECHA
0 2021-10-30
```

**BUT** if the dtype of your column `FECHA` is integer, you have to cast your column to string before:

```
df['FECHA'] = df['FECHA'].astype(str).astype('datetime64')
print(df)

# Output:
       FECHA
0 2021-10-30
```

Comment: I get this error:
ValueError: The 'datetime64' dtype has no unit. Please pass in 'datetime64[ns]' instead.

    my complete code

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime 

dataset_covid = "datasetcovid.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(dataset_covid, sep=";", usecols=["DISTRITO", "FECHA_RESULTADO"])
df['FECHA_RESULTADO'] = df['FECHA_RESULTADO'].astype('datetime64')

also try this other code
df['FECHA_RESULTADO'] = df['FECHA_RESULTADO''].astype(str).astype('datetime64')

ParserError: year 20210307 is out of range: 20210307.0

Comment: Just to be sure, can you try `pd.to_datetime(df['FECHA'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')`?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the result is caused by the parameters you are inputing in the `to_datetime` function. To fix this you should :

1. drop the `unit` parameter which is not related to your formating
2. add a format parameter which correspond to the date format you are using.

Hence, your code should go from:

```
df["FECHA"] = pd.to_datetime(df["FECHA"], unit='s')
```

To this:

```
df["FECHA"] = pd.to_datetime(df["FECHA"], format='%Y%m%d')
```

In order to find the proper formating you can lookup the values that correspond within this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). Docs related to the to_datetime function can be [found here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

---

In our scenario the `%Y` corresponds to a year with century as a decimal number.
The `%m` to a padded month (with a starting zero). And the `%d` to the day in the month. This should match the `20211030` (year - month - day) given.